# How to solve Typescript errors TS2307 Cannot find module

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, typescript

I keep getting `TS2307 Cannot find module error` whenever I run typescript checks on my project. The `src/index.ts` file has the following imports:

```
import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';
import {WebBundlr} from '@bundlr-network/client';
import {Connection} from '@solana/web3.js';
import type {Adapter} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
```

and my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext" ,
    "module": "esnext" ,
    "moduleResolution": "node" ,
    "baseUrl": "." ,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*", "node_modules/*"]
    } ,
    "resolveJsonModule": true ,
    "noResolve": true ,
    "allowJs": true ,
    "checkJs": true ,
    "declaration": true ,
    "declarationDir": "declarations" ,
    "isolatedModules": true ,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true ,
    "esModuleInterop": true ,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
    "strict": true ,
    "noUnusedLocals": true ,
    "noUnusedParameters": true ,
    "noImplicitReturns": true ,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true ,
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

According `package.json` and `node_modules` folder all packages are already installed and all of them are supposed to have built-in types:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",  
  "main": "lib/index.cjs.js",
  "module": "lib/index.esm.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "browser": {
    "./lib/index.cjs.js": "./lib/index.browser.cjs.js",
    "./lib/index.esm.js": "./lib/index.browser.esm.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "/lib",
    "/src"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@bundlr-network/client": "^0.8.5",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.16",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.59.1",
    "big-number": "^2.0.0",

    ....
    ....
  },
```

But I keep getting `module not found` errors for all those libraries:

[image]

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

> According package.json all packages are already installed and all of them are supposed to have built-in types:

The name of packages in package.json file doesn't mean they are already installed. Run `npm install` command first to install the packages.

Comment: In my case I use `yarn install`, but yes they are already installed and can be checked on folder `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` but that is definitely not the issue, I rather think it has something to do with the Typescript configuration.